# Can't send back object in multer method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload, multer

I'm performing a file upload via multer, and since I want to store the file in a specific location, as well as name it my own file name, I am using the `destination` and `filename` attributes that multer offers when creating the storage object.

The problem I'm having is I want to send back to the client the information of my newly created object after storing it in the database. However, there is no res parameter to do this and I can only do this in my post method, which does not have the object I just created.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads'); // Absolute path. Folder must exist, will not be created for you.
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var fileType = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
        var fileDestination = file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + fileType;

        cb(null, fileDestination);

        var map = new Map({
            mapName: req.body.mapTitle,
            mapImagePath: "./uploads/" + fileDestination,
            ownerId: req.user._id
        });

        Map.createMap(map, function(err, map){
            if(err)
                next(err);
            console.log(map);
        });
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('mapImage'), function (req, res) {

    res.status(200).send({
        code: 200, success: "Map Created."
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multer attaches the files to the request object, you have access to these in your post method:

```
app.post('/', upload.single('mapImage'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file.filename); // prints the filename
    console.log(req.file.destination); // prints the directory
    console.log(req.file.path); // prints the full path (directory + filename)
    console.log(req.file.originalname); // prints the name before you renamed it
    console.log(req.file.size); // prints the size of the file (in bytes)

    res.json(req.file);
});
```